# MySQL – JOIN automatically executes irrelevant SELECT expressions

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, cumulative-sum, sql-limit

In trying to implement a cumulative sum query with `JOIN`, I've run into a surprising problem: the cumulative sum expression is sometimes executed unexpectedly over the *entire* table, in an unexpected order, and with no adherence to `LIMIT`.

Consider the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( 
    v INT NOT NULL, 
    q_val INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE q ( val INT ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t VALUES 
    (5, 1), 
    (3, 1), 
    (1, 1), 
    (4, 1), 
    (2, 1);
INSERT INTO q VALUES (1);
-- (Table `q` exists solely for the purpose of the JOIN)
```

<sup>The data in `t` is entered out of order on purpose.</sup>

This is the query in question:

```
SELECT
  v, @cumulative:=@cumulative+v
  FROM t
  [INNER/LEFT/RIGHT] JOIN q ON t.q_val=q.val
  CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT (@cumulative:=0)
  ) z
  ORDER BY t.v DESC
  LIMIT 2;
```

We should expect to get the result on the left, but oftentimes we get the result on the right:

```
+---+----------------------------+      +---+----------------------------+
| v | @cumulative:=@cumulative+v |      | v | @cumulative:=@cumulative+v |
+---+----------------------------+      +---+----------------------------+
| 5 |                          5 |  VS  | 5 |                          5 |
| 4 |                          9 |      | 4 |                         13 |
+---+----------------------------+      +---+----------------------------+
```

If we remove the `LIMIT` clause on the queries that exhibit unexpected behaviour, we see what is really happening:

```
+---+----------------------------+
| v | @cumulative:=@cumulative+v |
+---+----------------------------+
| 5 |                          5 |
| 4 |                         13 |
| 3 |                          8 |
| 2 |                         15 |
| 1 |                          9 |
+---+----------------------------+
```

Clearly, in these case:

1. The sum is calculated in the "default" order of the table — the
   order without an explicit `ORDER BY` statement and, in this case, the order of insertion — and
2. It is being executed within the `JOIN` loops before the rest of the query somehow, circumventing the
   `LIMIT` restriction.

The second behaviour is particularly confusing, since the column from which the summation terms come from isn't even the one in the `ON` clause.

There are two factors that appear contribute to which behaviour is exhibited: combinations and types of indices (regular vs. `PRIMARY`), and type of `JOIN`. I have tested the combinations with significant results and have compiled them below:

[image]

<sup>** Strangely, using `INNER JOIN q FORCE INDEX(val)` makes the "KEY(q.val) AND KEY(t.q_val)" behaviour expected for some reason

* I suspect `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN` automatically creates the unexpected result in all cases, but `STRAIGHT_JOIN`-type JOIN seems to automatically create the *expected* result for all key combinations.</sup>

This begs the question: why is this happening? Are there other cases that exist? And, since this "default" order is [unpredictable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql) and [dangerous](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,239471,239688#msg-239688), can this behaviour be consistently avoided?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4583/2)

Comment: This this is why side-effect accumulators in queries should never have been allowed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing a side-effect accumulator, an ORDER BY, and a LIMIT clause yield unpredictable results. That's because the ORDER BY operates on the resulting rows *after* the accumulator result set is generated.  MySQL, and indeed all SQL table servers, return rows in formally unpredictable order in the absence of ORDER BY.   See, SQL Fiddle has the same problem you showed. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44007/4/0)

You can control the result by generating the resultset in a predictable order in a subquery, then using the (nasty MySQL hack of a) side-effect accumulator. Like so. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44007/10/0)

```
SELECT v, @cumulative := @cumulative+v
FROM (
  SELECT t.v
    FROM t
    LEFT JOIN q ON t.q_val=q.val
   ORDER BY t.v DESC
) a
JOIN (SELECT @cumulative := 0) b
LIMIT 2
```

### What is a side-effect accumulator?

The pattern in the query of this question involving `@cumulative` is the side-effect accumulator.  It's called that because `@cumulative := @cumulative+v` declares the contents of a result-set column and also produces a side effect (incrementing the variable).

SQL is a declarative language at its heart. A query, in its platonic-ideal form, doesn't say *how* to generate the result, it says *what* to generate. In the real world, SQL is littered up with pragmas and hints and side-effects.

The problem with such things is that they often depend on the internal details of how the server plans and carries out queries.  But, in a declarative language implemented by a competent query planner those details are intentionally obscure and unpredictable. The query planner is allowed (for efficiency's sake) to do anything it wants, in any order it wants, as long as it yields the correct result at the end. So it can carry out the side-effect computations however it pleases.

This questioner got caught by the obscurity of the sequence of row-generation and ordering operations, and the unpredictability of row ordering in results.

Notice that many of us would much rather have the MySQL and MariaDB teams spend their time implementing the ranking and windowing features available in other table servers than doing a lot of work to make these side-effect queries more predictable.  Ranking and windowing would give us declarative ways to generate the sort of result this questioner wants.

Comment: Forgive me, for I've never heard of the term "side-effect accumulator" before, but which part of the query is the accumulator? `@cumulative := @cumulative+v`?

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for this very thorough and well-written answer! Gives me a lot to look into.